# dicom3tools compiles with missing application pbmtoovl

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, dicom

I've downloaded dicom3tools in Ubuntu apt-get install dicom3tools, but certain apps are not present.
I've downloaded the source and compiled according to directions on Ubuntu without errors.  I have access to most of the apps in the kit, but some just seem to be missing or not compiling.
I need a working binary copy of the pbmtoovl tool from this kit.

Can anyone help me?
Do you know why it is missing?
Do I need to compile differently?
Do you have a copy of the pbmtoovl app pre-compiled?

There is no info on this anywhere on the web, I have nowhere else to turn.
Thanks in advance for any info on this.

Please please help me with this.....
I edited the proper file with a uid. 
I ran 
imake -I./config -DInstallInTopDir -DUsemyID 
and everything looked fine. 
make World. 
make install 
make install.man, 
but still no rawtodc or pbmtoovl or any of the dicom creation tools. I really need these tools. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. On Ubuntu 14 –

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the [dicom3tools](https://packages.qa.debian.org/d/dicom3tools.html) debian package. The explanation is given online [here](https://sources.debian.net/src/dicom3tools/1.00~20140902075059-1/debian/README.Debian/).

When you install a debian package, you are required to read the documentation. In this case the documentation was available on your system from:

```
$ cat /usr/share/doc/dicom3tools/README.Debian
```

So you'll need to follow the build instructions yourself (see `INSTALL`):

```
Edit config/site.p-def to set your UID root (a la UseClunieID, to be
selected with a UseXXXXID define on the imake command line).

NB. Don't ever use any UseClunie*ID or your instances
will conflict with mine !

./Configure
setenv IMAKEINCLUDE -I./config      # only needed for suns
imake -I./config -DInstallInTopDir -DUseXXXXID
make World
make install        # into ./bin
make install.man    # into ./man
```

Comment: So, to be clear, if I compile from the source on a debian system AND I stipulate the root UID,  will I get the pbmtoovl tool?  or do I have to use a non-debian system?

Comment: Please please help me with this.....I edited the proper file with a uid. I ran imake -I./config -DInstallInTopDir -DUsemyID   and everything looked fine. make World. make install make install.man, but still no rawtodc or pbmtoovl or any of the dicom creation tools.  I really need these tools.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  On Ubuntu 14

Answer (score -1):

I finally did a fresh Ubuntu install, installed xutils, g++, gcc and ran the compiling instructions.  It did not install, again, but this time I did have a new directory in bin ending in 'unknown' that miraculously contained all of the compiled binaries.  I added that dir to the PATH and VOILA I can access all the tools from the command line....
It's still a problem, but I can now use pbmtoovl